# How to override JSON translations for a Laravel package?

Tags: php, laravel, package, translation

I've built [a validation package](https://github.com/alariva/laravel-email-domain-blacklist) for Laravel >= 5.4 and it uses JSON translation files for the *validation message*.

I want to let the application to override that message translations.

[Laravel provides *namespacing*](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/localization#overriding-package-language-files) for `trans()`. However, It looks like only the regular `.php` translations allow namespacing.

I haven't been able to achieve this with JSON translations.

Currently, [this is how I'm returning the validation message](https://github.com/alariva/laravel-email-domain-blacklist/blob/master/src/Alariva/EmailDomainBlacklist/Validator.php#L68):

```
public function message($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters)
{
    return __('The domain for :attribute is not allowed. Please use another email address.', ['attribute' => $attribute]);
}
```

This is how I'm [loading the translation files in Service Provider](https://github.com/alariva/laravel-email-domain-blacklist/blob/master/src/Alariva/EmailDomainBlacklist/EmailDomainBlacklistServiceProvider.php#L18):

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->loadJSONTranslationsFrom(__DIR__.'/../../../lang', 'email-domain-blacklist');
    $this->publishes([
        __DIR__.'/../../../lang' => resource_path('lang/vendor/email-domain-blacklist'),
    ]);
    $this->publishConfig();
    // Add custom validation rules
    Validator::extend('blacklist', "Alariva\EmailDomainBlacklist\Validator@validate");
    // Add custom validation messages
    Validator::replacer('blacklist', "Alariva\EmailDomainBlacklist\Validator@message");
}
```

If I publish the translation files and alter them under `resources/lang/vendor/email-domain-blacklist/*.json` I will see no changes, since the package will load the translation from the package directory inside `vendor/`.

If I loaded the translations from the app level, I would require the application to always publish the translation files in order to correctly load them. I want to avoid this extra step.

Which would be an elegant way to go around this?

---

I will edit accordingly to provide as much clear info as possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found the way to go around this that Laravel proposes.

*Key overrides* in the **main project** JSON translation file (not in the `lang/vendor`, but directly in `lang/`) will take precedence.

[Reference here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/20599#issue-136044259)